# DS-160 Mistake B2 Tourism / Medical Treatment instead of B1/B2

Tags: b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I recently applied for my US Visa and in the DS 160 form, I selected B2 Tourism / Medical treatment instead of B1/B2, my purpose in traveling to the US is purely Tourism and I do not require any medical treatment. Do I need to refill the form and reschedule the appointment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input of `B2` seems to be more logical than selecting B1/B2. Please note that `B2` has an OR condition for tourism OR medical treatment.

`B1/B2` is logically more aligned for applicants with Business AND Leisure intent to travel to the US.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answer, also I want to share that I talked to a US VISA consultant and came to know its the only option if you are going for tourism or medical treatment. The us visa officer at the consulate will see your specific case and then give you a B2 TOURISM OR B2 MEDICAL TREATMENT visa depending the documents you show and also your intent to enter the US for business, tourism or medical. Hope this helps others.